# Azure file share – failed to delete files from Azure file share

Tags: azure, file, storage

Unable to delete files from Azure file share, please help with this. I already remove the server from all sync groups.
Please advise on this.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fde433a-aef0-49e9-8568-2aaf5a9b673a/unable-to-delete-a-file-from-azure-file-storage?forum=windowsazuredata , it helped me.

Comment: Thanks, Prerak K for valuable comment.                                                                      
I got a solution after unregistering the server. Simple troubleshoot I forgot it to unregister the servers Goo to -->Storage Syn Service -->Settings-->Registered servers --> Click on Server -->Unregister server -->Unregister

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution after unregistering the server. Simple troubleshoot I forgot it to unregister the servers Go to -->Storage Syn Service -->Settings-->Registered servers --> Click on Server -->Unregister server -->Unregister